# Insert failed due to Null ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51

Tags: mysql, vb.net, parameters

My questions :

What am doing wrong with this query, it confusing me a lot, can anyone suggest me the solution: am using the query as:

```
Dim constr As String = "Dsn=check;database=db;description=check;option=0;port=0;server=localhost;uid=root"
Dim con As New OdbcConnection(constr)
Dim mysql As String = "insert into parameter(col3,col1,col2) values(@val3,@val1,@val2)"
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand
With cmd
    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    .CommandText = mysql
    .Connection = con
    .Parameters.Add(New OdbcParameter("@val1", "C005"))
    .Parameters.Add(New OdbcParameter("@val2", "C006"))
    .Parameters.Add(New OdbcParameter("@val3", 55))
End With
con.Open()
MsgBox(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()) '<--- this line giving error as given below
con.Close()
```

> ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51
>   Driver][mysqld-5.0.37-community-nt-log]Column 'col3' cannot be null

but i am adding value to this parameter `.Parameters.Add(New OdbcParameter("@val3", 55))` then why this error is occuring?

The `col3` is primary key for my table. so if i put auto increment for the primary key field and then give values to `col1` and `col2` then it inserts `NULL` values to the table.

**If i use like the following : will works fine Problem occured while using the parameterised query, this is the first time am using parameterised query**

```
Dim mysql As String = "insert into parameter(col3,col1,col2) values(55,'C005','C006')"
    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand
    With cmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = mysql
        .Connection = con
    End With
    con.Open()
    MsgBox(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery())
    con.Close
```

am using **odbc driver 3.5** and **visual studio 2010**

[image]

The structure of the table am using:

```
CREATE TABLE  `db`.`parameter` (
  `col3` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `col1` text,
  `col2` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`col3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: If col3 is your auto-increment primary key then don't provide a value. The DB will insert it. `insert into parameter(col1,col2) values(@val1,@val2)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. it's not auto increment field. what am trying to say is. if i change it as auto inc. field and give the query as  `insert into parameter(col1,col2) values(@val1,@val2)`. then it inserts `NULL` for `col1` and `col2`

Comment: That is really odd. Can you add the table structure (with data types) to your question?

Comment: See my updates in the question>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table definition is wrong. Define your primary auto_increment key like this

```
CREATE TABLE  `parameter` (
  `col3` int NOT NULL primary key auto_increment,
  `col1` text,
  `col2` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then you can use this query

```
insert into parameter(col1,col2) values(@val1,@val2)
```

and the primary key will be generated by the DB.

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42ce1/1)

Also use `?` as parameter placeholders

```
insert into parameter(col1,col2) values(?,?)
```

Comment: no mistake in my query, if i execute the query in the query browser it works fine.and also works great if i give the query as `  Dim mysql As String = "insert into parameter(col3,col1,col2) values(55,'val1','val2')"` but when i use parameterised query it throws error

Comment: Try using `?` instead: `insert into parameter(col1,col2) values(?,?)`